# How to kill a spark job if application id is known?

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I am using dse with spark . I have submitted an spark job to master using dse submit . How to kill the job by knowing its application ID ?

Answer (score 0):

`dse spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill <spark-master> <driver-id>`

or

directly from the web UI (just ensure that spark.ui.killEnabled is set to true)

Comment: what is the driver ID here ? Is it same as application ID available in the UI ?

Comment: You can find the driver ID through the standalone Master web UI at http://<master url>:8080.

Comment: I am using DSE 4.7 and the master web ui port is 7080. When I use dse spark-class kill , I get Driver app-20150812102000-0000 has already finished or does not exist. But in the webui it is in waiting state. This scenario is hard to reproduce.